# How to detect if a variable lies in range for more than 2 seconds continuously in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dom-events

I'm writing this JavaScript code to detect if a live recording is silent for more than 2 seconds. I used a library to get mic level values and update it to a variable every 100 ms. (the function outputs values between 0-1 if it is silent and value larger than 1 if speech is present). I want to show an alert "You became silent" if the variable `levels` is in range 0-1 for 2 consecutive seconds.

```
var levels;
setInterval(function(){
  levels=meter.volume*1000;
},100);
```

How do I proceed with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reassigning a variable corresponding to the volume, when the volume is less than 1 *and* no timeout is currently set, set a timeout which runs after 2 seconds which alerts the user. Clear the timeout whenever the volume is greater than 1:

```
let timeout;
setInterval(function(){
  const vol = meter.volume * 1000;
  if (vol > 1) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
  } else if (!timeout) {
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("You became silent");
    }, 2000);
  }
},100);
```

Live demo:

```js
let timeout;
setInterval(function() {
  const vol = Math.random() + 0.05;
  console.log(vol);
  if (vol > 1) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
  } else if (!timeout) {
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      alert("You became silent");
    }, 2000);
  }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember the last time volume was loud. React if that was 2 seconds ago.

```
let lastLoud = new Date();
setInterval(() => {
  let now = new Date();
  if (now - lastLoud >= 2000) {
    console.log("You became silent");
  }
  let levels = meter.volume * 1000;
  if (levels > 1) {
    lastLoud = now;
  }
}, 100);
```